# How to Get GridView Row Values on ButtonClick using Javascript in asp.net?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, gridview

I have a `GridView` in my `asp.net` Applicaiton. i have a `Button` with `javascript` function which shows the values of `selected` row in `Div`. How to get all `Grid` `Column values of Selected Row on ButtonClick`.

[image]
Javascript:

```
function SetRowValues(id, controlid, fair, good, mint, nnew, poor,broken) {
            //alert(id + " " + fair + " " + controlid);
            $("#divSelectedRow").html("TPCCID: " + id + " Fair:" + fair + " Good: " + good + " Mint: " + mint + " New: " + nnew + " Poor: " + poor + " Broken: " + broken);
            $("#divSelectedRow").css("display", "block");
            return false;
    }
```

Grid Markup:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Source" ItemStyle-Width="50px" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"
    HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
    <ItemTemplate>
 <asp:Button ID="BtnSource" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" OnClick='<%# "return SetRowValues("+Eval("ttppcid")+",this.id,"+Eval("Fair")+","+Eval("Good")+","+Eval("Mint")+","+Eval("Poor")+","+Eval("Broken")+")"%>' Text="Source" />
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Here, i want to get all the column values of `selected row` using `Javascript`. 
**Note**: When the Value for column1 is string containing Space eg: "Cell Phone" then the script wont work.
Please help me to get the entire `row` values using `javascript` on `Button Click`.

Help Appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I think you have make mistake in preparing the Javascript function call.

Missing single quote around parameters '' .

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Source" ItemStyle-Width="50px" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"
    HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
    <ItemTemplate>
 <asp:Button ID="BtnSource" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" 
OnClick='<%# "return SetRowValues('"+Eval("ttppcid")+"',this.id,'"+Eval("Fair")+"','"+Eval("Good")+"','"+Eval("Mint")+"','"+Eval("Poor")+"','"+Eval("Broken")+"')"%>' Text="Source" />
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```